# aws-iot-device-sdk-js: thingShadow callback "on status" not being fired

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

i'm trying to solve a simple task using `aws-iot-device-sdk-js` and node.js. I want to subscribe to all updates made to the shadow and so something with them. I could do it using the `device` class using the certificates, but this is not available for the purpose of this demo.

Here is my code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var AWSIoTData = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var thingName = 'MyThing';
var shadowsRegistered = false;

var AWSConfiguration = {
   poolId: 'us-east-2:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX', // 'YourCognitoIdentityPoolId'
   host: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', // 'YourAWSIoTEndpoint', e.g. 'prefix.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
   region: 'us-east-2' // 'YourAwsRegion', e.g. 'us-east-1'
};

//
// Initialize our configuration.
//
AWS.config.region = AWSConfiguration.region;

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
   IdentityPoolId: AWSConfiguration.poolId
});

var shadowsRegistered = false;

iniShadows = function(credentials){
    const shadows = AWSIoTData.thingShadow({
       region: AWS.config.region,  // Set the AWS region we will operate in.
       host:AWSConfiguration.host, //Set the AWS IoT Host Endpoint
       clientId: 'some random string', // Use a random client ID.
       protocol: 'wss', // Connect via secure WebSocket
       //
       // Set the maximum reconnect time to 8 seconds; this is a browser application
       // so we don't want to leave the user waiting too long for reconnection after
       // re-connecting to the network/re-opening their laptop/etc...
       //
       maximumReconnectTimeMs: 8000,
       debug: true, // Enable console debugging information (optional)
       //
       // IMPORTANT: the AWS access key ID, secret key, and sesion token must be
       // initialized with empty strings.
       //
       accessKeyId: credentials.AccessKeyId,
       secretKey: credentials.SecretKey,
       sessionToken: credentials.SessionToken
    });
    shadows.on('connect', function(){
      console.log('connect');
      //
      // We only register our shadows once.
      //
      if (!shadowsRegistered) {
        console.log('=== registering shadows ');
         shadows.register(thingName,{
           persistentSubscribe:true
         },function(){
           console.log('after registerging. ');
           shadowsRegistered = true;

         });

      }
    });
    shadows.on('reconnect', function(){
      console.log('reconnect');
    });

    shadows.on('status', function(thingName, statusType, clientToken, stateObject) {
      console.log(thingName);
      console.log('----> got status ' + statusType);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(stateObject));
    });
    shadows.on('delta', function(thingName, stateObject) {
      console.log(thingName);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(stateObject));
    });
    shadows.on('timeout', function(thingName, clientToken) {
       console.log('received timeout on '+thingName);
    });    

}


var cognitoIdentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err, data) {
   if (!err) {
      console.log('retrieved identity: ' + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
      var params = {
         IdentityId: AWS.config.credentials.identityId
      };
      cognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function(err, data) {
         if (!err) {
            //
            // Update our latest AWS credentials; the MQTT client will use these
            // during its next reconnect attempt.
            //
            //shadows.updateWebSocketCredentials(data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            //   data.Credentials.SecretKey,
            ///   data.Credentials.SessionToken);
            iniShadows(data.Credentials);
              console.log('updated credentials in shadows ');

         } else {
            console.log('error retrieving credentials: ' + err);
            alert('error retrieving credentials: ' + err);
         }
      });
   } else {
      console.log('error retrieving identity:' + err);
      alert('error retrieving identity: ' + err);
   }
});
```

The log on the console is just:
    ... (some cognito output)
    updated credentials in shadows
    connect
    === registering shadows
    after registerging.

so the cognito part is working, and I'm able to register the thing.

The `shadows.on('status',...` and `shadows.on('delta',` are never called. Even if there is data flowing, because I can register to the shadow/updates/accepted in the AWS IoT mqtt client.

I then tried to call `shadows.get(thingName)` from within the callback of the register function AND I got the callback for `status` working once. However, the callback does not work for every new message that gets accepted by the shadow.

```
if (!shadowsRegistered) {
        console.log('=== registering shadows ');
         shadows.register(thingName,{
           persistentSubscribe:true
         },function(){
           console.log('after registerging. ');
           shadowsRegistered = true;

           opClientToken = shadows.get(thingName);
         });

      }
```

As you can see, I have no trouble authenticating or other stuff. It is probably just a misunderstanding of how the shadow class works. Any help highly appreciated.